# Какие есть способы получить слитный текст из списка в python

Tags: python, строки, list

У меня есть список, к примеру:
`letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

Какие есть способы помимо цикла, чтобы получить строку с слитными данными из списка:
`print(result) Результат: abcd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используейте join
https://pythonru.com/osnovy/python-join

`result = ''.join(letters)`

Comment: Ах, да, точно, забыл за ''.join(), давно уже с им не работал

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте

```
print(*letters, sep='')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]